# How to iterate a particular item in array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to do different iteration to elements in single array.

```
arr = ["1111", "2221", "7ext", "3345"]
```

I want to run a block that would slice only the element that contains letters and elements with no letter remain the same.
The result would be following

```
arr = ["1111", "2221", "7", "e", "x", "t", "3345"]
```

I do not know neither how many elements would be in array or order.
All elements are strings.

Comment: Your result is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
arr = ['1111', '2221', '7ext', '3345']
arr.flat_map { |e| e =~ /\D/ ? e.split('') : e }
# => ["1111", "2221", "7", "e", "x", "t", "3345"]
```

Comment: You can eliminate `flatten` by using [flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map). Aside: one of my sons lives near Cali (Lake Calima).

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks, great suggestion - and BTW: Cali is called "Heaven's outpost" for a good reason :) I'm glad for your son, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.flat_map{|s| s.split(/([a-z])/i)}.reject(&:empty?)
# => ["1111", "2221", "7", "e", "x", "t", "3345"]
```